# Figure out what a query locks other queries in SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, locking

We use SQLServer 2014 and periodically some of the queries lock other queries. It happens at unexpected intervals of time. In such situation, you can quickly run necessary management scripts to find out which exactly query is a locker. But if you late you will lose with information.
Is there in SQLServer any tools to analyze a history of locking between transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to find out which queries are BLOCKING others?

To find out which queries are blocking others, try using the blocked process report.

Tips on use and configuration can be found [here](https://www.brentozar.com/sql/locking-and-blocking-in-sql-server/). There is also a link here for a blocked process report viewer, which is extremely helpful (kudos to Michael J Swart).

Comment: Ok, maybe you right and more correctly call it blocking processes. Anyway, the problem is that I can not be on the computer all the time. And I need to find such processes which cause blocking 5 hours later, for example.

Comment: @Spinifex3 - That is what the blocked process report does - you configure a threshold and if there is blocking over that threshold it fires an event that you can capture with SQL trace or extended events